# Cannot seem to come up with right parameter for _set_se_translator

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to implement _set_se_translator.  I tried to write a function with the following signature (from my .cpp file - of course, I have a similar signature in my .h file):

```
 void CIntersonBScan::trans_func(unsigned int u, EXCEPTION_POINTERS* pExp)
```

I then pass this function as a parameter to _set_se_translator by writing the following code:

```
 _set_se_translator(&CIntersonBScan::trans_func);
```

I then compile my code and get the following error message:

error C2664: '_set_se_translator': cannot convert parameter 1 from 'void(__thiscall CIntersonBScan::*)(unsigned int,EXCEPTION_POINTERS *)' to '_se_translator_function'

In the eh.h file, I found the following definition for _se_translator_function:

```
 typedef void (__cdecl *_se_translator_function)(unsigned int, struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS*);
```

I tried varying the signature of trans_func and still got the same error message.  I already set the /EHa compile option.  How to I create a function that would actually match the signature of _se_translator_function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
typedef void (__cdecl *_se_translator_function)(unsigned int, struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS*);
```

This must be a free function, or a static member function - it cannot be a non-static member function (because these have a hidden implicit `this` parameter - and cannot match `_se_translator_function`).

Comment: Thanks for your help! I converted the function into a static function. I thought I tried using a free standing function, but it looks like I did something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It needs to be a free standing function, not a member function. That is why the types don't match.